# Classification Problem With Estimated and Dependent Covariates

Tags: classification

I have a dataset that contains estimated posterior membership probabilities for an unordered, 5 level categorical variable. These sum to unity. The data looks like this:

```
id  pred1       pred2        pred3       pred4       pred5
1   .859171     .03846882   .03101809   .00917879   .06216329
2   .36325043   .4150897    .07394462   .01415896   .13355629
3   .15642941   .70247179   .08668463   .01269947   .0417147
4   .95966166   .00182377   .00850792   .01247164   .01753501
5   .93548764   .02308354   .00776801   .00950647   .02415434
6   .98533042   .00024188   .0036747    .00361082   .00714217
7   .73908375   .1286123    .13230396    0           0
8   .64286514   .0447184    .26215937   .02530076   .02495633
9   .90968365   .0175316    .05905972   .00243294   .01129209
10  .95854473   .01169418   .00776546   .01392006   .00807557
```

Here observation 1 probably belongs to k=1, and observation 2 is more divided between 1 and 2. Most of the observations come from class 1.

I also have a data set of true values that were not used in the model for about 100K observations.

I would like to develop a set of reliable and interpretable threshold rules that assign unique category membership given pred1-pred5 that are are less prone to misclassification than just going with the highest posterior probability estimate. I care the most about distinguishing group 2 from group 1 correctly (both type I and II error rates) than other types of misclassification. I suppose I care more about type I error.

I am struggling with how to translate this to a misclassification cost matrix for a classification tree to use. I have tried doing something like this (the code below does not match the fake data above as far as ordering of the groups):

```
# rows are actual values, columns are predicted value
# Type II penalty below diagonal, Type I penalty above
    MCM <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,1,
                    2,0,2,2,3,
                    1,1,0,1,1,
                    1,1,1,0,1,
                    1,4,1,1,0), 
                  byrow=TRUE,
                  nrow=5,
                  dimnames = list(sort(unique(phats$outcome)), sort(unique(phats$outcome))))              
    # grow tree
    fit <- rpart(outcome ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + pred4 + pred5,
                 data = phats,
                 method='class',
                 parms=list(split='information', loss = MCM),
                 )
    # prune the tree by picking the tree which minimizes the CV error
    pfit<- prune(fit, cp=fit$cptable[which.min(fit$cptable[,"xerror"])])
```

Comment: Can I ask why hard and fast classification is of interest?  I think most people would say that the raw probability is of real interest because it lets individuals apply their own utility function for the probabilities.  For instance, your second observations are quite split between classes 1 and 2, and outright labeling this observation is belonging to either class is questionable in my own opinion.

Comment: @DemetriPananos That's a reasonable question. I would like to report some experimental results by estimated class. The experimentation system is not able to run a regression, so it needs to have discrete variables. I was trying to do that in a way that improved on just going with the highest posterior probability. My initial instinct was to layer a classification tree on top of the predictions and and adjust the costs to get something more sensible in cases like obs 2.

Comment: I think this is a case where you might want to examine misclassification rate more than the probabilities (“proper scoring rules”). However, $50\%$ is a fairly arbitrary cutoff. @DemetriPananos what would you think of tuning the threshold as a hyperparameter? (At the same time, if you get a predicted probability of $51\%$, perhaps the best option is not to include that point, since you’re basically flipping a coin to determine class membership, so perhaps the proper scoring rules rule the day yet again!)

Comment: @Dave That might be a reasonable first go at things, but I'm a little stumped here.